# Ошибка пи вызове другого фрагмента

Tags: android, recyclerview

Здравствуйте. При при переходе с одного фрагмента и последующем заполнении recyclerview выходит ошибка Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. Изза чего это может быть ?

Comment: потому что вы пытаетесь обратится к View не из UI потока.[пример](http://www.seostella.com/ru/article/2012/02/14/android-oshibka-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-views.html)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте с помощью Handler 
Жаль что мы не можем видеть ваш код

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, уже разобрался